# Polynomial fit doesn't plot high degrees

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm working now with regression and tried to fit polynomial model to my data with 3 different degrees and it plots only the lowest degrees. I have no idea where I'm going wrong. Here is my code and data points:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt
import time

def main():
    inputfile = "statistics.txt"
    X= np.loadtxt(inputfile, delimiter=",",dtype=np.str, usecols=[0])
    X= [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y') for date in X]
    X = mdates.date2num(X)
    Y= np.loadtxt(inputfile, delimiter=",", usecols=[1])
    num_training = int(0.9*len(X))
    num_test = len(X) - num_training
    X_train, Y_train = X[:num_training], Y[:num_training]
    X_test, Y_test = X[num_training:], Y[num_training:]
    plt.scatter(X_train, Y_train, color="blue",s=10, marker='o')
    plt.title("Euro Swedish Krona Exchange rate")
    plt.xlabel("Time in months from April to June in 2017")
    plt.ylabel("Exhange rate")
    colors = ['teal', 'yellowgreen', 'gold']
    for count, degree in enumerate([2, 3, 4]):
        coeffs = np.polyfit(X_train, Y_train, degree)
        f = np.poly1d(coeffs)
        x_line = np.linspace(X[0], X[-1], 50)
        x_line_plot = mdates.num2date(x_line)
        y_line = f(x_line)
        plt.plot(x_line_plot, y_line, color=colors[count], linewidth=2, label="degree {}".format(degree))
        print(coeffs)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())    
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

-----statistics.txt-----

```
11.04.2017,9.6059
12.04.2017,9.5741
13.04.2017,9.5976
14.04.2017,9.5892
17.04.2017,9.5763
18.04.2017,9.6101
19.04.2017,9.6107
20.04.2017,9.6309
21.04.2017,9.6611
24.04.2017,9.6266
25.04.2017,9.5858
26.04.2017,9.5551
27.04.2017,9.6070
28.04.2017,9.6474
01.05.2017,9.6438
02.05.2017,9.6220
03.05.2017,9.6326
04.05.2017,9.7007
05.05.2017,9.6669
08.05.2017,9.6616
09.05.2017,9.6649
10.05.2017,9.6974
11.05.2017,9.6489
12.05.2017,9.6480
15.05.2017,9.6903
16.05.2017,9.7402
17.05.2017,9.7432
18.05.2017,9.7797
19.05.2017,9.7800
22.05.2017,9.7683
23.05.2017,9.7363
24.05.2017,9.7255
25.05.2017,9.7378
26.05.2017,9.7233
29.05.2017,9.7138
30.05.2017,9.7580
31.05.2017,9.7684
01.06.2017,9.7402
02.06.2017,9.7256
05.06.2017,9.7388
06.06.2017,9.7707
07.06.2017,9.7833
08.06.2017,9.7685
09.06.2017,9.7579
12.06.2017,9.7980
13.06.2017,9.7460
14.06.2017,9.7634
15.06.2017,9.7540
16.06.2017,9.7510
19.06.2017,9.7475
20.06.2017,9.7789
21.06.2017,9.7676
22.06.2017,9.7581
23.06.2017,9.7629
26.06.2017,9.7537
27.06.2017,9.7647
28.06.2017,9.7213
29.06.2017,9.6806
30.06.2017,9.6309
03.07.2017,9.6479
04.07.2017,9.6740
05.07.2017,9.6332
06.07.2017,9.6457
07.07.2017,9.6084
10.07.2017,9.6101
11.07.2017,9.6299
```

I think that its something with dates because I got plot working without dates. There could also be something too much in my code. Its also weird that by changing degree values I sometimes get 3 curves and sometimes only 1.

Comment: You could show us your .txt file, besides explaining the error you get.

Comment: If you zoom into your figure you will see It _does_ plot all three, however they are very close together.

Answer (score 4):

As @DavidG pointed out in a comment, the three curves are very close, so they look the same unless you zoom in.

That is just a symptom of the problem.  You probably noticed the warnings that were printed when you ran the code.  These indicate a numerical problem occurring in `polyfit`.  Your `X` values are relatively large and very close together.  Apparently they are large enough to cause problems in `polyfit`.  One way to avoid this is to subtract the mean from the `X` values, so they are centered around 0.  (You might also consider dividing the shifted data by its standard deviation.  This combined shifting and scaling is known as *whitening*.  In this case, simply shifting the data is sufficient.)

Here's modified version of the fitting and plotting code that does this shift of the `X` values (I tweaked the colors and style a bit, too):

```
colors = ['teal', 'darkgreen', 'black']
markers = ['-', ':', '--']
alphas = [1, 1, 0.25]
mu = X_train.mean()
for count, degree in enumerate([2, 3, 4]):
    coeffs = np.polyfit(X_train - mu, Y_train, degree)
    f = np.poly1d(coeffs)
    x_line = np.linspace(X[0], X[-1], 50) 
    x_line_plot = mdates.num2date(x_line)
    y_line = f(x_line - mu)
    plt.plot(x_line_plot, y_line, markers[count], color=colors[count],
             linewidth=1+2*(count==2), alpha=alphas[count],
             label="degree {}".format(degree))
    print(coeffs)
```

It turns out the degree 3 and degree 4 curves are still close, but they are quite different from the degree 2 curve:

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you for the brilliant answer! What I learned from this problem was that I should use markers with color and there is useful preprocessing techniques to avoid errors! Here is follow up question: Now I have learned about regression that there is linear and polynomial and also sinusoid etc. kind of function to fit curves to data. Although sometimes I have to use preprosessing methods to modify my data (learned from here). If I have understood correctly numpy's polyfit uses least squares method as estimator.

Comment: Can I use some other estimators that I can find in numpy (I know that in sklearn I can use Ridge Bayasian ect.) because numpy is simply software to use. Is there anything else that i SHOULD KNOW about regression and curve fitting?

Comment: That question is a bit too broad to answer in a comment on SO, and I don't feel qualified to answer what anyone "should know". :)  A question like that might be appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Okay I'll try to learn subject regression by myself. I have last one question: How can I estimate with some factors that which degree fits best to data? If there is several factors im curious to see how to implement curves performance with factors. (I have know that there is so called overfit ting problem and Tikhonov/Ridge is trying to solve it.)